# How to correctly use dev/urandom for random generation

Tags: random, c

Runs before main:

```
 d -c 30 /dev/urandom > random.bytes
```

Access the randomly generated numbers

```
int main() {
   FILE *fp;

   int fd = open("random.bytes",O_RDONLY);

    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
   if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));

    }

    char buffer[8];
    //int error =  read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer) );

    if( fgets (buffer,sizeof(buffer), fp)!=NULL ) {
          /* writing content to stdout */
          puts(buffer);
             }
   fclose(fp);


    if ( error < 0) {
              fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));

                }
    uint8_t tid = atoi(buffer);
    printf("%d\n",tid); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output is always 0?

Comment: This appears to be a programming question rather than a security question. Perhaps it's because your `read` call is commented out?

Comment: Nope read wasn't working so I switched to fgets

Comment: You're calling `fgets` on `fp` which is a handle to `file.txt`, not `random.bytes`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading from a random dump, you should read from urandom directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
        int i;
        unsigned char buffer[8];
        int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, buffer, 8);
        //buffer now contains the random data
        close(fd);
        for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: good answer, any idea as to why my previous code wasn't working?

Comment: Why `O_RDWR` instead of `O_RDONLY`?

Comment: @forest Supposedly writing to urandom won't cause any negative effects, so I figured it might as well open as read write in case the user wants to write to it. If it's early in the boot phase and the system doesn't have writable disks for storing entropy from the previous run then it might be worthwhile to read data from an external server to write it to urandom.

Comment: @user That's true, but it's usually a good idea to only open a file with the mode you need. And as for writing to the entropy pool early at boot, [I think it's not immediately useful](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/183506/165253) due to the way the kernel collects entropy.

Comment: @forest I agree that in this case it doesn't make sense to open it as read/write.